# Remote connection to server without port forwarding

Tags: windows

I am trying to setup a way for me to remotely log-in to my server at work. However, I cannot setup port forwarding on the router because our previous system administrator just randomly quit and I do not have the passwords to the routers. Therefore, the only way for me to gain access would be to reset the whole network (which I plan to do during a vacation period when there is nobody here).

For the moment, I would like to be able to log-in to the server from an external network so I do not have to travel all the way to work to fix simple things. By the way, the server is running windows server 2003 SP2.

Comment: Do reverse connection. From server to you. There is many solutions for this, one example is setting up reverse VPN with [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/)... I have successfully used this method to setup servers behind ISP firewalls.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend solution like [LogmeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) or similar. It's free and allows to add multiple computers to the account. It gives you multiple settings and adjustments per bandwith and you will be able to remote to any previously added computer just by using your Internet browser.

LogmeIn requires following actions:

1. Login to the PC you want to remotely be able to login.
2. Register with LogmeIn and add a PC to you account.
3. Install LogmeIn software that will reside in a tray as a service
4. Leave the PC power on.

Now from outside of the network, login to LogmeIn. You will be able to click a button to open remote connection with one of your computers.

On a side note - Lack of access to network routers and rest of network infrastructure is a ticking bomb. I wouldn't postpone too much the necessary actions to regain the access.

Comment: Logmein, Team Viewer, and GoToAssist all use port 80/443. These should  cut right through the firewall.